# objdump disassemble executable compiled with -marm as thumb instructions

Tags: gcc, arm, disassembly, thumb, objdump

I have compiled some code with gcc -marm, and then when I try to disassemble it with objdump, half of the instructions are 16 bits, so I guess it is thumb instructions. Why ?

I have seen this question :
[objdump and ARM vs Thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194134/objdump-and-arm-vs-thumb)

So I tried to disassemble it with objdump -marm -b binary -D, however the disassembly seems very odd...

How I can know if this is gcc which used thumb instructions despite the -marm option, or if it is objdump which is buggy ?

EDIT : here is a fraction of the disassembly with 16 bits instructions :

> Disassembly of section .init:
>
> 00008304 <_init>:
>      8304:    b508          push    {r3, lr}
>      8306:    f000 f849     bl  839c 
>      830a:    bf00          nop
>      830c:    bd08          pop {r3, pc}

Comment: What is `gcc`s output format?  Binary, ELF, or something else?

Comment: Normally it is elf. I am not sure about the .s (how can I get this information from the .s ?), but when I disassemble the executable, it is written that it is elf32-littlearm

Comment: can you provide some examples/fractions of sections with label names that you think are thumb?

Comment: If it is an *ELF* file, then just `objdump -S file.o` should work.  The **objdump** has to be *ARM* aware.  You can not use a normal PC **objdump**.  Ubuntu has a *multi-arch binutils*, and the **objdump** in that version will understand *ARM*.  Make sure the **objdump** is from the same place as your `gcc`.

Comment: I have tried to use objump -S but it doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: I have forgot to say, I used objdump at the place I have compiled my code